# React native remove header from home screen

Tags: react-native

I have made my custom header and i want to remove react-native default header.

> I have tried with
>
> 1. Setting option "header: null" in navigationOptions of
>    createBottomTabNavigator
> 2. header:null in HomeScreen.js file

but it's not working. Please help to solve this issue. Here is my navigation code. I am attaching screenshot exactly what i want to remove.
[image]

```
import React from "react";
import { Platform } from "react-native";
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "react-navigation-tabs";
import TabBarIcon from "../components/TabBarIcon";
import HomeScreen from "../screens/HomeScreen";
import SavedScreen from "../screens/SavedScreen";
import BookingScreen from "../screens/BookingScreen";
import BeAHostScreen from "../screens/BeAHostScreen";
import ReferEarnScreen from "../screens/ReferEarnScreen";
import BookingInnerScreen from "../screens/BookingInnerScreen";
import { Icon } from "react-native-elements";

const config = Platform.select({
  web: { headerMode: "screen" },
  default: {}
});

const tabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen,
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      title: "App Name Here"
    },
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: "Home",
      tabBarOptions: {
        activeTintColor: "#00E8AC"
      },
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
        return focused ? (
          <Icon name="md-home" type="ionicon" color="#00E8AC" />
        ) : (
          <Icon name="md-home" type="ionicon" color="#ccc" />
        );
      }
    }
  },
  Saved: {
    screen: SavedScreen,
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      title: "Saved"
    },
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: "Saved",
      tabBarOptions: {
        activeTintColor: "#00E8AC"
      },
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
        return focused ? (
          <Icon name="md-heart" type="ionicon" color="#00E8AC" />
        ) : (
          <Icon name="md-heart" type="ionicon" color="#ccc" />
        );
      }
    }
  }
});

const MyApp = createStackNavigator(
  {
    BookingInner: BookingInnerScreen,
    Tabs: {
      screen: tabNavigator
    }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Tabs"
  }
);

export default MyApp;
```

Comment: headerShown: false, try with this

Comment: Try removing your screen from stack navigator if you have pushed into it, so it will automatically be removed

Comment: @GauravRoy it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
const MyApp = createStackNavigator(
  {
    BookingInner: BookingInnerScreen,
    Tabs: {
      screen: tabNavigator
    }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Tabs",
    headerMode: 'none',
  }
);
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't read the code you posted well, I have updated my response hope it will work now (which it will)